# More efficient code to test node names

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In the game I'm making I have a heart count at the bottom. The idea is to remove one heart when the user touches a "bomb". Right now, I create all hearts at the beginning of the program and name each one "heart1" "heart2" and "heart3". In the doDamage method, add 1 to the hitCount when the user touches a bomb. Then I proceed to remove the heart. I have this code right now. Is there any better and more efficient solution for this? Heere's the code I'm using right now.

```
- (void) doDamage {

    //Sets the isDamaged value to yes and adds a hit point

    isDamaged = YES;
    hitCount++;
    NSLog(@"The hit count is %i ", hitCount);

    //calls the damageDone method after a second to avoid being damaged all the frames the bomb touches the basket
    [self performSelector:@selector(damageDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    //This lengthy code is used to test what heart should be removed each time...

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"heart1" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){

        //If the hitCount is the same as the heart we want to remove, then we'll remove it from the parent
        if (hitCount == 1) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
            }];

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"heart2" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){

        if (hitCount == 2) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
            }];

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"heart3" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){

        if (hitCount == 3) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
            }];
}
```

Comment: If there is only one node each for "heart1", "heart2", etc then you do not need to use the code [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:], you can just use [self childNodeWithName:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest hiding the heart nodes instead of removing them, because then you can bring them back anytime (powerups or something).

```
SKNode *heartNode;

switch (hitCount)
{

    case 1:
        heartNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"heart1"];
        break;
    case 2:
        heartNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"heart2"];
        break;
    case 3:
        heartNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"heart3"];
        break;

}

if (heartNode)
{
    [heartNode setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this should work? When I use this with the heart node I have, I see an error saying "incompatible pointer types assigning SKSpriteNode * from SKNode *"

Comment: In that case, change SKSpriteNode *heartNode to SKNode *heartNode

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this already has an accepted answer, but if code speed is important wouldn't this be quicker...

```
SKNode *heartNode = [self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"heart%d",hitCount]];

[heartNode setHidden:TRUE];
```

If `heartNode` is `nil` then the `setHidden` does nothing

Just not sure if doing `stringWithFormat` is quicker than a `switch` statement